# Scala Play Forms verify that one date occurs after another

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

My form has two dates, but I want to validate that the second date occurs *after* the first date. Is there a concise way to do this using Play's Form verification?

Here is the form I am working with:

```
  val policyForm: Form[PolicyForm] = Form(mapping(
    "amount" -> of[Double].verifying("You need to enter in the amount of bitcoins", _ > 0),
    "beginDate" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd").verifying("You cannot have a start date before today", dayLater _ ),
    "endDate" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd").verifying("End date has be after the start date", { d => 
      ???


    })
    )(PolicyForm.apply _)(PolicyForm.unapply _))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference other form fields within the same `mapping` until after they all successfully bind individually. That is, the constraint must be made on the outer `mapping`.

```
val policyForm: Form[PolicyForm] = Form {
  mapping(
    "amount" -> of[Double].verifying(...),
    "beginDate" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd").verifying(...),
    "endDate" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd")
  )(PolicyForm.apply _)(PolicyForm.unapply _).verifying("End date has be after the start date", policyForm =>
     policyForm.beginDate.before(policyForm.endDate)
  )
}
```

This assumes `java.util.Date`, so replace with your own logic if you're using joda time, or something else.